# How can I use dynamic value in map function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Hi is there any way to use a dynamic value in `.map()` of javascript function which is coming from outside?

Example:

```js
data.map(item=> item."dynamic");
```

How to do this? or is it possible at all?
I want to do this because, I want to use this map not for a single value like `item.name` but dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Try with square (`[]`) bracket that allows dynamic property:

```
data.map(item=> item[dynamic])
```

Comment: Yes that helps me but, if i want to go a little bit deeper than its not actually working.
i mean if i pass something like  "details.photo"  its not working :/

Comment: @Ozzie, I believe there is no built-in way to achieve that:)

Comment: so if i pass a value like "data.user" will it work?  to access in a object in the item?

Comment: @Ozzie, no, that will not work.........